# How to fix Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../../ when deploying Firebase Functions on Gitlab CI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gitlab-ci

I have a Firebase project with Typescript functions

When I install, build and deploy from my console using firebase deploy all works fine.

But, when I try to do the same using my .gitlab-ci.yml script I get an error that it can't find my relative import.

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module '../../config/version'
Require stack:
```

The Typescript code is:

```
// utilsController.ts
import { serverVersion } from '../../config/version'
```

And that is converted to

```
// utilsController.js
const version_1 = require("../../config/version");
```

And apparently firebase deploy does not like this when running on Gitlab CI, but it works without a problem from my machine.

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "incremental": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "target": "es2015",

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,

    /* Additional Checks */
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* Experimental Options */
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this error go away and I am pretty sure is was an update of tsconfig.json, that did the trick. Probably the "target" should be "es2017" for my setup to work.
I simply created a new Firebase Functions Typescript project using firebase-tools CLI and departed in the tsconfig from that.
New, working tsconfig is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    /* Experimental Options */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```